# Can't print an exported shield ui grid to excel

Tags: excel, shieldui

I'm trying to print an excel that was exported from a shield ui grid, but whenever i do so, excel stops working and crashes. If I save as the worksheet, close excel and open it again then I can print it, but this is very uncomfortable for the user. Even I can't print the excel given in the demo: https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/export-to-excel

I've tried in various pc's to make sure that it wasn't a problem of repairing excel or a problem with the download folder.

Any sugestions on how to make this work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool does not show any error for the .xlsx file generated by that URL.

You can temporarily switch the generated Excel file to the older XML format if your Excel is raising an error.

Comment: Thank you, now I can print the exported table.